# DOM modyfication after jQuery load() code injection

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, refresh

into DIV:

```
<div id="materialcolor"></div>
```

I must incject this dynamically generated code:

```
<select class="groupsmaterialcolorsDDs" name="group_6" id="group_6" onchange="putLayer(document.getElementById(this.id).value);">

    <option id="futura_perspective_merita_aubergine.jpg" value="76" selected="selected" title="Aubergine">Aubergine</option>

    <option id="futura_perspective_merita_bordeaux.jpg" value="100" selected="selected" title="Bordeaux">Bordeaux</option>

</select>
```

I do this via jQuery's load() funcion from other location:

```
/ajaxcreator.php?product_id=14
```

Before AJAX's request the function putLayer() in select's onchane parameter works (It's changing the other DOM's elements - put a background from ids of this select). After AJAX Request - not.

I probably must refresh the DOM elements to try again modyfi them. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't see an AJAX request, or any Javascript for that matter in your question, well except for that piece of code in `onChange()` which references a function that is not in your question.

Comment: You can replace the html with `putLayer( this.value )`, `document.getElementById(this.id)` doesn't make much sense

Comment: OK works! It was my mistake... I missed one parameter in returned by AJAX code... Also I replaced odd document.getElementById to this.options[this.selectedIndex]. Problem solved... THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  the jquery '.on'   function to make sure the event handler is always attached to all future '.groupsmaterialcolorsDDs' in that div.

example:

$('#materialcolor').on('change', '.groupsmaterialcolorsDDs', function(){

putLayer(this.value);

});